# Automatically reset corrupt NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to internally recover from a corrupt NSUserDefaults in iOS? For example, is there a specific exception that is raised in this case, which I could then gracefully respond to? I think some of my users are experiencing crashes on startup because of corrupt settings (they don't email me so I don't know the specifics) and it would be nice if my app could automatically reset the NSUserDefaults when this happens.

A related question: How can I purposely corrupt NSUserDefaults to test this situation?

Comment: A better question: Why are the defaults becoming corrupted in the first place? It's unlikely it's NSUserDefaults that's doing this. Look carefully at any places where defaults are written, and see what it is you're writing.

Comment: When you say corrupted, do you mean it has got garbage values? And if yes, check if you code can handle unexpected values and then reset to default.

Comment: These are both excellent points. I am (very unfortunately) not sure of the specific circumstances of the crashes, and have not experienced them in my testing, but nevertheless I am sure that I could use more safeguards in reading defaults values. Maybe this is an ill-defined question without more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try a lucky guess:

Try adding a check on a class of an object in `NSUserDefaults` at startup. So before any of them are used in the code. Or check on some other stuff depending what should be there.

And to "corrupt" it I'd try storing an `NSArray` instead of `NSNumber` for example. And then re-running the app.

Hope it helps

Comment: As suggested above in the comments, I ended up just adding some more code to all my NSUserDefaults reads, making sure that the values make sense. After doing quite a few tests, I could never get NSUserDefaults to crash, so it must be what I do with the values that was causing the problem.